# Adding a column in a data frame which is the rank for the positive elements of another two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame in R:

```
d=data.frame(x=c(0,20,0,12,0,73),y=c(22,0,32,0,5,0))

   d
    x  y
 1  0 22
 2 20  0
 3  0 32
 4 12  0
 5  0  5
 6 73  0
```

Now I want to create another column `rank` which will take values 1 for the smallest positive value of `y`, 2 for the second smallest positive value of `y`, 3 for the third smallest positive value of `y`, 4 for the smallest positive value of `x`, 5 for the second smallest positive value of `x`, 6 for the third smallest positive value of `x`. That is my desired output is:

```
   d
    x  y rank
 1  0 22 2 
 2 20  0 5
 3  0 32 3
 4 12  0 4
 5  0  5 1
 6 73  0 6
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your plan for ties?

Comment: @PierreLafortune there will be no tie because x, y will be continuous.

Comment: Will you have cases where x and y are both zeroes? Or cases where they both are not zeroes?

Comment: you can try :`d[order(d$x,d$y),"rank"] <- 1:length(d$x)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune if x is 0, then y will be a positive number. If y is 0, then x will be a positive number.

Comment: @HubertL that's brilliant. Add as answer please with explanation.

Comment: @HubertL It's working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ranking by y when x=0 then by x when y=0 is the same as ranking first by x, then by y, so you can use `order` to order by x then y, and assign a rank in that order:

```
d[order(d$x,d$y),"rank"] <- 1:dim(d)[1]
   x  y rank
1  0 22    2
2 20  0    5
3  0 32    3
4 12  0    4
5  0  5    1
6 73  0    6
```

Comment: It works because `order` allows for multiple vectors as arguments. Whenever there is a tie in one vector, the next will be used, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Or a modified option would be to call `order` on the `order` output

```
d$rank <- order(do.call(order, d))
d
#   x  y rank
#1  0 22    2
#2 20  0    5
#3  0 32    3
#4 12  0    4
#5  0  5    1
#6 73  0    6
```